# Monodevelop code highlight - highlighting the method name in method declaration

Tags: monodevelop, syntax-highlighting

In Monodevelop 4, when I select the Visual Studio color scheme, the names of methods in method declarations appear slightly purple. In the example below, it would be `GetSomeString`.

I do not want, however, to highlight usage of methods (in the example below, this would be `GetOtherString()` in `this.GetOtherString()`.

The second, I can control with the Method(Semantic) parameter in the Monodevelop color scheme, however I found no way whatsoever to change the first one (although in the visual studio scheme it is slightly purple, while in the default scheme it is not, so it does change...)

```
public lass SomeClass
{
    protected string GetSomeString() {
        return this.GetOtherString() + "SomeString";
    }

    protected string GetOtherString() {
        return "Other";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a built-in style, you'll have to make a copy of that style and edit the generated .xml file. I believe the lines you want are:

```
<Style name="keyword.semantic.method" color="#(hex color)" />
<Style name="keyword.semantic.method.declaration" color="#(hex color)" />
```

Modify those to your liking.

Alternatively, if you have Semantic Highlighting turned on, turning that off should also remove it (along with all other semantic highlighting, though)

The .xml file of your created style, at least on Windows, should be stored in C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\MonoDevelop-Unity-(version#)\HighlightingSchemes\

A quick google search should tell you where the mac equivalent is, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you can point me to some reference that lists the syntax of this XML? I'd like to know all the style names, and what style parameters are available (so far I saw color, weight and bgColor. Are there more? Like font size or underline?)

Comment: I've yet to find a resource like that (if only...!) but there are some helpful examples in the default styles in xml on their github before they moved to .json:

https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/5a6c1a560619f08104098b5defc65a55c697611e/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Styles

Beyond that, tinker and tweak 'til you get the effect you want :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. How about the two specific examples - can I change the font size, or underline a word?

Comment: To find this on OSX it is in ~/Library/MonoDevelop-Unity-4.0/HighlightingSchemes/...